# How to load XML elements' content separately to Python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an XML file named 'config.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <set1>
    <data1> data content </data1>
    <data2> data content 2 </data2>
    <data3> data content 3</data3>
    <data4> data content 4 </data4>
 </set1>

 <set2>
    <data1> data content </data1>
    <data2> data content 2 </data2>
    <data3> data content 3</data3>
    <data4> data content 4 </data4>
 </set2>
```

In here I tried to get the content of `set1`. Suppose we can't say exactly what is going to be included in `set1` data tag names and the amount may change from time to time because I use this as config file of my application. I used XML because `set2` also included in the XML file. but I want to read only 1 set for one time.

XML `set1` tag content reading is ok it's working fine but I need to append the content of `set1` or `set2` just like below.

```
 datalist = ['data content','data content 2','data content 3','data content 4']
```

How can I do that with BeautifulSoup4? Because when I read the content of `set1` or another set my code give the whole content the same time. there is no separation. So I need to do extra work to separate them like `"split"`, `"strip"`.

How can it do it with the only bs4? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the tag in question (`set1`) and then extract the content of each child tag of it.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
set1 = soup.find('set1')
[x.string.strip() for x in set1.children 
                  if type(x) == bs4.element.Tag]
#['data content', 'data content 2', 'data content 3', 'data content 4']
```

Comment: It's working!. perfect and Thank you very much @DYZ